# How I can set a dot to center of MacBook monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

Actually, I'm a gamer and for better shooting, I wanna set a `dot` to the center of my MacBook screen. in some games like Call of duty or CSGO this dot help me to better shoot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a ruler and a Marker.

Measure diagonally and place a Dot with marker in the center, that you can wash off later.

Comment: I do it with a white marker, but I wanna do it programmically

Comment: @AmerllicA that would be difficult  (or impossible)to do. What you are asking is to create a transparent overly screen (over your game screen) with a stationary dot, but it has to be non-active so not to interfere with Game. I am not aware of such capability.